# Ubuntu Rails Development Environment WITH Gnome?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I'm new to Rails development and I am currently setting up a dev VM (using VMware and 10.04lts 64 Ubuntu, to match my production server). Not having any problems, but...

I vastly prefer Gedit + GnomeTerminal + Nautilus/Filezilla to the sluggish cygwin + console2 + notepad++ setup I have in Windows7.

**Will I compromise my development tests and troublshooting by installing Gnome on my Dev VM?**

Answer (score 2):

the short answer is no :)
And you'll find linux way more friendly to Ruby development (which you probably already know)